# Microsoft Access backend .accdb file shared with Apache Web Server using WebDAV could not be linked as an external data

Tags: apache, ms-access, webdav

I think I've advanced in this direction much but this seems to be the last problem I ran out of clues how to resolve.

My intention was to split my Microsoft Access (.accdb) database into a backend(pure tables) and a frontend(forms, queries, reports, etc.) and to share the backend over the Internet.

First, I have succeeded with splitting.
In Microsoft Access, if you click External Data -> Access, the "File name" field will only accept UNC path name. Say, when I share my database via LAN (Homegroup), Windows on a client machine gives me a UNC like **\\SERVERNAME\FolderName\MyDatabase_be.accdb**, which I can (and did) use to link my backend file to the frontend file. I have tested it, it works fine for me. Okay, that is fine.

Second, I have succeeded with installing Apache Web Server, switching its' WebDAV on, allocating a directory to host my database tables file in. I have set up **httpd.conf**:

```
    Listen 192.168.0.101:80
    LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
    LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
    LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
    LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
    LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
    LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
    LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
    LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
    LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so

<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

I have also configured the **http-dav.conf**:

```
Alias /sites "C:/database/database"

<Directory "C:/database/database">
    Dav On

    Require all granted

    AuthType Digest
    AuthName DAV-upload

    Options Indexes

    AuthUserFile "C:/Apache24le/user.passwd"
    AuthDigestProvider file

    # Allow universal read-access, but writes are restricted
    # to the admin user.
    <LimitExcept GET OPTIONS>
        require user admin
    </LimitExcept>
</Directory>
```

and **httpd-vhosts.conf**:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/database"
    <Directory "C:/database">

    <VirtualHost _default_:80>
        DocumentRoot "C:/database"
    </VirtualHost>
```

My Apache Web Server is behind a router, so I also had to: 
1. set up **port forwarding** on my router; 
2. make DHCP assigning the same IP to my server's MAC address each time;

Using standard Windows functionality, I have mapped a network folder to my system so it becomes fully accessible. **It also has produced a UNC** for this location (watch the picture below)

[UNC name provided by Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owYeG.jpg)

which was supposed to be my goal, so I even could point my Microsoft Access to it. But I cannot open that file!!! When I try to open directly or refer from Microsoft Access the database file, Microsoft Access gives me a message

> "Your network access was interrupted. To continue, close the database,
>   and then open it again"

[An error message, which is the main concern of this post!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xe9AA.png)

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fully understand what's going on, you'll need to think at a low level regarding how Access reads and writes data from the .accdb file. When Access talks to that file locally, or on the lan over a UNC/SMB, it's able to use block level I/O calls to open, seek, read, write, close the .accdb file and gain access to the information in chunks. This is standard Windows based File I/O in action.

So now you've put that .accdb file out to a remote WebDAV server and you are using the Microsoft WebDAV redirector to talk to that same .accdb file. This time, Windows will use WebDAV as the protocol instead of standard old SMB or direct File I/O.

The Microsoft WebDAV redirector, because it's DAV based, operates at an atomic file level rather than a block level. This means that when Microsoft Access issues a File Open + File Read call, the low level MSDAV redirector will do a complete GET on the remote file and copy the entire .accdb file to your local temp folder before allowing MS Access to get to it. Take that one step further and if Access does a Seek(EOF-1byte) followed by a read(1byte), the WebDAV redirector will need to download the entire .accdb file before the seek/read can complete.

There are very few WebDAV based redirector technologies on the market which allow for block level I/O paging type requests over WebDAV. And for most of those, they only do block reads, they can't do block 'writes' because you also need a DAV server that supports the http range header on a PUT. This means that if Access tries to touch the very last byte of the .accdb file, the MS Redirector will read, touch, then write the entire file to and from the apache WebDAV server.

Full Disclosure: We have had WebDAV support in our WebDrive product for nearly 15 years now and we've seen so many of our customers who are trying to accomplish this exact same thing. They want to stick an Access DB up on a DAV server and then share and access it from a Windows client that runs either MS Access or some other type of custom Windows app that talks to Access.

While you may be able to eventually get the solution to work (provided you find a DAV client and DAV server that both support http range requests and block level dav locking), I'm not quite sure you will be pleased with the overall performance. You'll also probably have issues with concurrency when two different clients attempt to get to that same .accdb file at the same time. the Microsoft redirector will give each user a copy of that .accdb file and in the event that they both modify the file, you can't really predict which file will get pushed out to the Apache mod_dav first, and which will get overwritten with the other copy.

If you really want to split your data storage and your forms/ui/presentation layer, you would be best served to move your tables/views to sqlserver or sqlite and then have your MS Access Forms/Queries/Reports use standard TCP/IP or NP to access the DB in a traditional client-server deployment. You could run SqlExpress locally and have port 1433 forwarded through your firewall instead of using Apache/mod_dav.

Sorry if I don't have a very specific answer to your question; your idea is very logical. It's just that we've seen so many others try unsuccessfully to implement this I want to make sure I pass along the information for you.

I hope you get a solution that works for you!

Comment: thanks. I have uploaded my backend (database tables) into the MySQL database (import -> CSV) which was hosted by my hosting provider, and I have installed the MySQL Connector ODBC driver (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=467704) on each clients' machines, as well as set up Administrative Tools -> ODBC Data Courses (64-bit) (since I've installed the 64-bit ODBC driver) -> System DSN -> add -> chose the newly installed MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver, and since then I found myself capable of linking tables in Microsoft Access with an ODBC option. Works great for me.